# Connecting isolated grounds of TES1-2411

Tags: dc-dc-converter, ground

Traco's TES1-2411 DC/DC converter has isolated input and output grounds and it is obviously a needed feature in a lot of applications. However, I would like to use it in an application where I need to connect the two grounds together. I suppose it can be done but just in case, is anyone aware of any issues with this?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, since it is an isolated DC/DC converter that can handle up to 1500V potential difference between input and output, it can surely handle 0V between input and output as well.

If you don't need isolation then the isolated converter can work but just costs extra.

Answer (score 0):

I have just got a response from the supplier saying the grounds can be connected (losing galvanic isolation of course) but EMC performance may change (for the better or for the worse).